# How to make a function usable for multiple instances? eg player1, player2,

Tags: php, laravel, oop

It seems I forgot anything and now stuck an this little thing.

There is a **match** between **multiple players** in **two teams**. How do I have to write this function to make it handle every player?

**Match.php**

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->redTeam = new Team();
    $this->blueTeam = new Team();
    $this->player1 = new Player('Bensen');
    $this->player2 = new Player('Kicksen');
    $this->startMatch();
}    

public function fightCreeps()
{   
    $creeps = 0;
    $gold = 0;
    for ($this->wave; $this->wave > 0; $this->wave--) {
        if ($this->player1->lasthitting >= rand(1, 100)) {
            $creeps++;
            $gold += 40; 
            $this->player1->creeps++;
            $this->player1->gold += 40;
            $this->player1->totalGold += 40;
            $this->player1->experience += 40;
            $this->player1->health -= rand(5, 10);
        }
    }
    return "<span style=\"color: red;\">{$this->player1->name}</span> has slain {$creeps} Creeps. +{$gold} Gold<br>";
}
```

Comment: Hint (if I understand your question correctly): `public function fightCreeps()` => `public function fightCreeps(Player $player)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to consider your app architecture. From an OOP point of view, the `Match` doesn't `fightCreeps()`, the `Player` fights creeps.

I would define the relations differently (see https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships). For example, if you know there are only ever going to be two teams playing in a Match, then on the Match model, you define:

```js
use App\Team;

class Match extends Model {

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        // when a match is created, auto-create teams
        static::created(function ($match) {
            $match->redTeam()->create([]);
            $match->blueTeam()->create([]);
        });
    }

    public function startMatch()
    {
        //fight
    }

    public function redTeam()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Team::class);
    }

    public function blueTeam()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Team::class);
    }
}
```

Team model:

```
use App\Match;
use App\Player;

class Team extends Model {

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        // when a team is created auto-add players
        static::created(function ($team) {
            $team->players()->create(['name' => 'Bensen']);
            $team->players()->create(['name' => 'Kicksen']);
        });
    }

    public function players()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Player::class);
    }

    public function match()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Match::class);
    }

}
```

Player Model:

```
use App\Team;

class Player extends Model {

    public function team()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Team::class);
    }

    public function fightCreeps()
    {
        // fight!
    }
}
```

Then, you can do things like:

```
foreach ($this->redTeam->players as $player) {
    $player->fightCreeps();
}
```

You can, of course vary how you create the teams and players, but I think these are the general relationships that you want.

In Laravel relationships, multiple relations are automatically returned as a `Collection` (https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections), which is a fancier version of an array. If you want, you can manually create a collection yourself and then loop through it, like so:

```
$players = collect([$player1, $player2]);

foreach ($players as $player) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public $players = [];

public function __construct()
{
    $this->redTeam = new Team();
    $this->blueTeam = new Team();
    $this->addPlayer('Bensen');
    $this->addPlayer('Kicksen');
    $this->startMatch();
}


public function addPlayer($name)
{
    $this->players[] = new Player($name);
}


public function startMatch()
{
    // do other starting match related stuff

    foreach ($this->players as $player) {
        $this->fightCreeps($player);
    }

}

public function fightCreeps(Player $player)
{
    // do the fighting stuff
}
```

Comment: But this still has the problem of hardcoding everything inside the class. Not really feasible or extensible

Comment: I'm all for making the class with better design principles, but at this point i have no idea how it's being used, this is just a better adaptation of what OP currently has